# The difference between prefetch_related and model_set in Djnago

Tags: python, django, orm

## I wonder what is the best flow when I need to retrieve foreign key model objects.

is it to use **prefetch_related** in views.py like:

```
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('book_set')
context={objects:queryset}
```

or to use directly in the template by **model_set**:

```
{% for attach in objects.book_set.all %}
```

what is better and which one is good for performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) is used to select all related objects for all parent objects in advance mostly used with `ManyToMany` field and a reverse relationship.

While as [model_set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) is used to get all related objects of a single parent object which will definitely have more database hits.

Hence it is better to do `prefetch_related` as it will reduced the database hits significantly.

If you are not doing reverse relationship and have foreign key relation then [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) is prefered.

As far as writting queries in template or views is better. I would suggest always do all queries in the view as templates add extra level of overhead.

Comment: So if I use prefetch_related in views and in the template I use model_set too in the second for-loop it wouldn't hit the database again, right?

Comment: Yes that will not do database hit but you don't have to use `prefetch_related` in template just in views will do.

Comment: I think you did'nt get my point , if I use prefetch in views and use model_set in template the model_set will hit the DB or not ?

Comment: As I said no it won't hit database as you have used prefetch_related in view. I already mentioned it in previous comment

Answer (score 0):

The best approach depends on your specific use case and the content and size of your database. However, generally using `prefetch_related` in the `views.py` can provide better performance by reducing database queries.

Here's an example to clarify both approaches:

1. Using `prefetch_related()` in views.py:

```py
# views.py

queryset = Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('author')
context = {'books': queryset}
```

```html
<!-- template.html -->

{% for book in books %}
    {{ book.title }} by {{ book.author.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

In this approach, the `prefetch_related('author')` fetches all related authors in a single query, reducing the number of database hits.

2. Using `model_set` in the template:

```html
<!-- template.html -->

{% for book in books %}
    {{ book.title }} by
    {% for author in book.author_set.all %}
        {{ author.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

While on the second approach, each iteration of `book.author_set.all` hits the database to retrieve the related author object. This can result in multiple database queries, and different sort of problems, especially if you have a large number of books.